# What is difference between In app billing and Google wallet?

Tags: android

I developing the android app which uses In app purchase. The Core of purchase is when the user clicks the button, It will send the bids to all companies. Here, I am going to integrate In app purchase flow before sending bids to companies. So the user need to pay 1$ to send bids to all companies. Google has In app billing and Google wallet Instant buy APi for android.  I don't know which API should i use?. Please Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1-[Google Play In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)
To sell digital content from inside your applications.

2-[Google Wallet Instant Buy Android API](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial)
Used only for physical goods or services.

As you want to sell apps, the best option is 1.

Comment: I am not selling any digital content in my app. Instead, just charge 1$ when user clicks. Is this comes behind In app billing or Google wallet?. I think I should use Google wallet.

Comment: Ok, you sell a service, so you should use Google Wallet but as your kind of monetizing is ambiguous I would choose it depending of the commissions.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: use the In app billing. It already contains sample code and is suitable for your use case. Setup a consumable good so that the user has to pay everytime. You can then see the purchased items in your Google wallet merchant account.
The Google wallet Instant buy is more targetted at web sites / apps and thus is more targetting B2B in my opinion.
Also see this:
https://developers.google.com/wallet/which-api?hl=de

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference in how big the fee is that Google charges for in-app purchases (30%) and digital or non-digital goods via Google Wallet ( less than 5% ). I have yet to find a description of what kind of products that qualify as one or the other, though.